# -bash: pip: command not found

Tags: macos, pip

**I installed pip this way:**

```
$ sudo easy_install pip
Searching for pip
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Best match: pip 1.5.4
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-1.5.4.tar.gz#md5=834b2904f92d46aaa333267fb1c922bb
Processing pip-1.5.4.tar.gz
Running pip-1.5.4/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-rl8K1T/pip-1.5.4/egg-dist-tmp-ikFNCe
warning: no files found matching 'pip/cacert.pem'
warning: no files found matching '*.html' under directory 'docs'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.rst' found under directory 'docs/_build'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build/_sources'
Adding pip 1.5.4 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pip script to /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
Installing pip2.7 script to /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
Installing pip2 script to /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin

Installed /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip
```

**when I try to use pip, got below error information:**

```
$ pip
-bash: pip: command not found
```

**what should I do now? please help, thanks.**

Comment: Seems like a `$PATH` issue.  Try:  `/usr/bin/pip` ?  And fix your $PATH in your `.bashrc` perhaps?

Comment: $ /usr/bin/pip

-bash: /usr/bin/pip: Too many levels of symbolic links

Comment: Normally, there isn't a `/usr/bin/pip` on OS X.

Answer (score 2):

You can see from the above output that the `pip` command has been installed to `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin`.  You don't say which version of OS X you are running on but that is not the default location for scripts when using the Apple-supplied system Python; normally, scripts, like `pip`, would be installed in `/usr/local/bin` which is normally included in `$PATH`.  You should figure out why scripts are being installed into the framework bin directory.  Perhaps you have a `~/.pydistutils.cfg` file with a non-standard configuration?

Comment: seems that I mess up my python environment already, how can I recover mac default python environment? My OS X is 10.8.3, thank you in advance

Comment: It's hard to tell from the information you've given what state your system is in.  The safest and most reliable way to return your system to a known state is to re-install OS X. Since you are running an out-of-date system now, you *might* consider just upgrading to OS X 10.9 Mavericks.  In the future, avoid modifying, adding, or deleting files in `/System/Library` and `/usr` other than `/usr/local`.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

the file of pip is in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin 
coz it not on your path so it can't be found. just create a link to fix the problem:
$sudo ln /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin /opt/local/bin/pip
that's it. I got the same problem and fixed it this way.